# Best way to have a custom FloatField with an editable comment parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django and I mostly write code for scientific and engineering applications. Python is great for these and I find myself wanting to share some of the apps with a better interface - hence my interest in Django.

In one application that I'm trying to port over to Django, there are dozens of parameters that each have a comment associated with them that is user editable. This is done so that the user can keep track of the reasons for these values.

A simple example is:

```
class Parameters(models.Model):
  telescope = models.ForeignKey(Telescope, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  p_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  start_date = models.DateTimeField()
  end_date = models.DateTimeField()

  az_A = models.FloatField('Azimuth A', help_text='words of wisdom')
  az_B = models.FloatField('Azimuth B', help_text='words of wisdom')
  az_C = models.FloatField('Azimuth C', help_text='words of wisdom')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.p_name
```

For the case that I'm working on now, the values 'az_A', 'az_B', 'az_C' are fixed and cannot be edited in the form where the comments can be entered. It is important that the comments get stored in the database (and associated with the proper parameter).

The next case is where similar values 'az_A', 'az_B', 'az_C' can be edited as well as the comments associated with them.

Do I need to make a custom model field or is there a better way? I've already used the help_text for a static comment and I'm under the impression that I cannot alter this text through a form (correct?)

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

> In one application that I'm trying to port over to Django, there are
>   dozens of parameters that each have a comment associated with them
>   that is user editable.

If I understand you correctly, you are describing at least two distinct fields: the float, and the text. You won't be able to have them as a single field on the model.

You probably want to investigate defining a form that can be re-used to display and edit the two fields together on a page.

If you have a comment that describes the field (*not* just one value of it), then you want to set that comment in the `help_text` attribute of the field.

Comment: What I'm hoping that I can create is a single entity that can have a float and a comment that I could access with code like thing1.value = 23.34 and thing1.notes = "This value will be less than 30 for most situations." I can clearly do this with a class, but then I don't know how to build a Django model that uses classes and not fields.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a [MultiValueField field type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.MultiValueField) that is to be subclassed for situations where a form displays two or more fields that are turned into a single value to be stored in the database. In reverse, a single database value can be parsed and represented by multiple form fields.

Why would you do this? One example is shown by looking at the wonderful [django-measurement](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-measurement) library, which allows for unit conversions (see the [forms.py](https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-measurement/blob/master/django_measurement/forms.py) source for an example of the methods used in subclassing MultiValueField). The MultiValueField is subclassed for a MeasurementField, which consists of a FloatField (for a value) and ChoiceField (for the unit of measurement desired). So, for instance, distance could be input as inches, millimeters, or miles and is always converted to a base unit when cleaned for the database. When retrieving values from the database, the measurement can be converted from the base unit to whatever unit makes the most sense for the user.

**If** there is standard logic for what the uneditable comments would be, that could be validated at the MultiValueField level and raise a `ValidationError` if it has been changed. Otherwise, allow for editability.

This is a complex solution and so it's hard to give a code example, but it is also the perfect solution for dependent fields if you aren't afraid to get your hands dirty with some advanced Django.